# How do I extend the expiration date of every DNSSEC signature in bind9?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dnssec

I have a dnssec-secured domain that needs to remain valid for 8 weeks when all masters become unreachable.

To my understanding, setting `sig-validity-interval` to `64 7` in the zone's configuration file should generate `SSIG`s that last 64 days and that are automatically resigned by bind9 every 7 days.

When I finished implementing this for the domain, I was suprised to see dnsvis showing me that not all generated `RRSIG`s last 64 days. The `RRSIG`s for both `DNSKEY` and `SOA` do last the expected duration, but all other `RRSIG`s expire after 11 to 14 days.

I initially thought this might be a caching issue caused by running bind9 before setting the signature validity interval. So I stopped `named`, cleared `/var/cache/bind` and removed all DNSSEC files `*.jbk`, `*.jnl`, `*.signed`, and `*.signed.jnl`, then restarted bind again. This did not resolve the issue.

It's obvious I'm doing something wrong here but I don't know what. Below are the configuration snippets I use for the domain:

1. Zone declaration in `named.conf.local`:

   ```
   zone "example.com" {
        type master;
        file ".../db.example.com";
        allow-transfer  { ... };
        also-notify     { ... };
        inline-signing yes;
        auto-dnssec maintain;
        serial-update-method increment;
        key-directory "...";
        sig-validity-interval 64 7;
    };
   ```
2. Contents of `.../db.example.com`:

   ```
   $TTL 300
   @    IN  SOA ns1.example.com. admin.example.com. (
            2021101004      ; Serial
            10m             ; Refresh
            20m             ; Retry
            9w              ; Expire
            1h )            ; Negative Cache TTL
   ;

   example.com. IN  NS  ns1.example.com.
   example.com. IN  NS  ns2.example.com.

   ; ...
   ```

Answer (score 0):

As of bind version 9.16.15 (~2021), it seems that bind only allows control over when `RRSIG` records expire when [custom dnssec-policies](https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dnssec-guide.html#creating-a-custom-dnssec-policy) are used:

1. First, a custom policy is defined with the options `signatures-refresh`, `signatures-validity`, and `signatures-validity-dnskey` set to the desired values.
2. Then, the custom policy is enabled for a given zone by setting the `dnssec-policy` option in the zone block.

A custom policy might look something like this:

```
dnssec-policy example-com-policy {
  dnskey-ttl 300;
  keys {
      ksk key-directory lifetime unlimited algorithm ED25519;
      zsk key-directory lifetime unlimited algorithm ED25519;
  };
  max-zone-ttl 300;
  parent-ds-ttl 300;
  parent-propagation-delay 2h;
  publish-safety 7d;
  retire-safety 7d;
  signatures-refresh 1439h;
  signatures-validity 90d;
  signatures-validity-dnskey 90d;
  zone-propagation-delay 2h;
};
```

And the zone block might look something like this:

```
zone "example.com" {
     type master;
     file ".../db.example.com";
     allow-transfer  { ... };
     also-notify     { ... };

     key-directory "...";
     serial-update-method increment;
     dnssec-policy example-com-policy;
};
```

Be warned, this method comes with a few downsides when compared to the traditional method (i.e. `auto-dnssec maintain`):

1. I've found that bind becomes unresponsive to `rndc`/`systemctl` commands when a single policy is used for multiple domains. Defining a separate policy for each zone seems to have fixed this issue.
2. I've found that bind [insists on "retiring" your KSK and ZSK keys regardless of whether they expire or not](https://serverfault.com/questions/1080271/how-do-i-prevent-bind-from-retiring-non-expiring-dnssec-keys-when-using-dnssec-p). I have not found a way to avoid this issue at the time of this writing.

From what I can tell, this is equally applicable to bind in both master and slave configurations.